# Managing oversold inventory conditions in Magento

Tags: php, magento, edi

I have been using the [Bluecherry](http://www.harapartners.com/bluecherry-magento-connector/) for managing stocks . Now there have been conditions during festive seasons where products have been oversold . Is there any way , that can be controlled as from what it's understood is that the Bluecherry resets the quantity part periodically every hour. Any suggestions in this regard would be much appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a sync based integration between two systems (with multiple channels of stock movement) you'll never have completely real-time info and you'll always have the risk of overselling. One workaround is to use a built-in Magento feature which lets you specify the quantity at which a product goes out of stock (under the Inventory tab). This can be used to create a psuedo-stock-splitting system to account for inventory that is sold off via other channels between the running of sync jobs between Magento and Bluecherry. The value you use here would depend on your business requirements and how much your stock is selling off via non-Magento channels.

Comment: I know about the inventory option you said , but how can we split that option . Can you please elaborate a bit more on that .